# include php inside json

Tags: php, json

I have table (data) and I need to insert some php inside

How do I do that?

**my code :**

```
$data['produit'] =  '       
        <label for="designation" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Désignation</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="NEED PHP HERE FOR EXAMPLE" id="designation" readonly>
        </div>
        <label for="prix" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Prix </label>
        <div class="input-group col-sm-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" name="prix" id="prix" readonly>
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">€</span>
        </div>
        ';
```

i need to do something like that :

```
$data['produit'] =  ' <input type="text" class="form-control" 
    name="' . echo 'test' . '" id="designation" readonly>';
```

Comment: If you mean you want literal PHP inside a string to eval later. Do yourself a favour and stop right now. There must be a better way. If on the other hand you mean adding PHP variable content into the string, a simple concatenation should do?

Comment: In your latest update, just remove the `echo` in the middle.

Comment: What is not happening here?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to concatenate your string with your PHP variables.  In php the concatenation operator is a period (.)

Here's an example that inserts a variable containing my name in your string, as well as a function that returns your name being inserted in your string.

```
$myName = "Robert";

function yourName() {
    return "Lucas";
}

$data['produit'] =  '<label for="designation" class="col-sm-1 control-label">' . $myName . '</label><div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="NEED PHP HERE FOR EXAMPLE" id="designation" readonly></div><label for="prix" class="col-sm-1 control-label">' . yourName() . ' </label><div class="input-group col-sm-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" name="prix" id="prix" readonly><span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">€</span></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it this way , since php is the server language it is compiled before the (HTML,JS...) parts, instead you can produce the results you wish within the server part and send it using JSON.